# Highcharts annotations - how to draw rectangle by axis points?

Tags: highcharts

I need to draw a rectangle and other shapes in HighCharts

Going to use a built-in annotations module, but unable to create a simple Rectangle by xAxis & yAxis points

For example - here's the Shape I'm trying to create

```
  annotations: [{
    shapes: [{
      type: 'rect',
      points: [
        {
          xAxis: 1,
          yAxis: 20
        }, {
          xAxis: 10,
          yAxis: 20
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
```

E.g. I wanna stretch it diagonally from 1:20 to 10:20

By documentation such way may work, but it's not.

Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shape` object isn't defined in correct way, because  `xAxis` and `yAxis` parameters are used to specify **which** axes the point will be connected to.
Second reason why your implementation is not working is the fact that you didn't specified any `height` and `width` values of the shape.

If you would like to draw a rectangle between two points (if I clearly understood your expectations), please use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer.rect()` function to generate it.
You can simply calculate the `x` and `y` values of a `rect` you need to create by `Axis.toPixels()` value, which converts the axis values to plot pixels values.

Another, and in my opinion the best solution is by creating new **fake** series, which has only the points for your annotations (and it's unaccessable for users), then create a shape `path`type with all points from that series  connected to it. Here is the code and example:

```
  series: [{
    data: [{
      y: 29.9,
      id: 'min'
    }, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, {
      y: 216.4,
      id: 'max'
    }, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }, {
    name: 'Fake annotations points',
    // To make this series hidden and unaccessible for user.
    type: 'scatter',
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    showInLegend: false,
    //
    data: [{
        x: 0,
      y: 29.9,
      id: '1'
    }, {
        x: 0,
      y: 216.4,
      id: '2'
    }, {
        x: 8,
      y: 216.4,
      id: '3'
    }, {
        x: 8,
      y: 29.9,
      id: '4'
    }]
  }],

  annotations: [{
    shapes: [{
      type: 'path',
      points: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    }]
  }]
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/quag6ey2/